# How to format a date w/ Month and Day in Joda

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to display a date as just a month/day string with Joda. Using a pattern works like a charm for English but that isn't really going to fly for localized versions.

For example:

```
5/14/2012 -> 
English = May 14  (The pattern here is MMMM d)
Spanish = 14 de Mayo (The pattern here is d 'de' MMMM)
```

Comment: So what's the exact question?

Comment: If you want more specialised locale based date formats, you can change the format to suit the locale.

Comment: And bear in mind, even for English literals in patterns can be necessary, for example to print "1st of May".

Comment: I thought the question was obvious. Is there a way to get a locale-specific date format string for month and year? It seems like the only way to get locale-specific is with the formatting styles. I'll just have to keep my own list of formats per language I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This involves translating between languages, of which is too complicated for the standard libraries; And Joda-Time is a Date/Time library, not a language translator library.

The date format is not necessary 'locale-specific', its '**language**-specific'. Your going to need to use a separate library or web API for it if you want the format to be compatible with all/most of the locales.